Generating background and theme colors for manifest in pwa from material theme
Is there a way to generate colors for PWA manifest from material UI 3 theme? I have light mode primary and primary-container colors, so I could just use those. I worry that if user changes to dark mode the colors will look bad. Should I be using on-primary instead of just primary color?

I actually found the variable in theme file that is just named "background". So I suppose that the primary along with background colors is what I'm looking for.
